# Proper regex (re) pattern in python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm trying to come up with a proper regex pattern (and I am very bad at it) for the strings that I have. Each time I end up with something that only works partly. I'll show the pattern that I made later below, but first, I want to specify what I want to extract out of a text.

Data:

- Company Fragile9 Closes €9M Series B Funding
- Appplle21 Receives CAD$17.5K in Equity Financing
- Cat Raises $10.8 Millions in Series A Funding
- Sun Raises EUR35M in Funding at a $1 Billion Valuation
- Japan1337 Announces JPY 1.78 Billion Funding Round

From that data I need only to extract the amount of money a company receives (including $/€ etc, and a specification of currency if it's there, like Canadians dollars (CAD)).

So, in result, I expect to receive this:

- €9M
- CAD$17.5K
- $10.8 Millions
- EUR35M
- JPY 1.78 Billion

The pattern that I use (throw rotten tomatoes at me):

```
try:
    pattern = '(\bAU|\bUSD|\bUS|\bCHF)*\s*[\$\€\£\¥\₣\₹\?]\s*\d*\.?\d*\s*(K|M)*[(B|M)illion]*'
    raises = re.search(pattern, text, re.IGNORECASE) # text – a row of data mentioned above
    raises = raises.group().upper().strip()
    print(raises)
except:
    raises = '???'
    print(raises)
```

Also, sometimes the pattern that works in online python regex editor, will not work in actual script.

Comment: Can you show an example where it works online but not in your script?

Comment: Hi @mkrieger1,
After watching a lot of materials about regex I tried to create another pattern (not the one demonstrated above), and for the case where it worked online, failed in the script. Unfortunately, I didn't save that pattern because of this failure

Comment: What currency is `?`

Comment: Hello, @trincot. This is how I tried to say to a pattern that those currencies are variable. For example, if I have something like "... JPY 1.78 Billion ...", there is no currency sign. I understand, that I need to put **"?"** mark out of brackets somewhere, but when I did so, it was breaking the pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues in your regex:

- The list of currency acronyms (AU USD US CHF) is too limited. It will not match JPY, nor many other acronyms. Maybe allow any word of 2-3 capitals.
- Not a problem, but there is no need to escape the currency symbols with a backslash.
- The `\?` in the currency list is not a currency symbol.
- The regex requires *both* a currency acronym as a currency symbol. Maybe you intended to make the currency symbol *optional* with `\?` but then that the `?` should appear unescaped *after* the character class, and there should still be a possibility to not have the acronym and only the symbol.
- The regex *requires* that the number has decimals. This should be made optional.
- `(K|M)*` will allow `KKKKKKK`. You don't want a `*` here.
- `[(B|M)illion]*` will allow the letters `BMilon`, a literal pipe and literal parentheses to occur in any order and any number. Like it will match "in" and "non" and "(BooM)"
- The previous two mentioned patterns are put in sequence, while they should be mutually exclusive.
- The regex does not provide for matching the final "s" in "millions".

Here is a correction:

```
(?:\b[A-Z]{2,3}\s*[$€£¥₣₹]?|[$€£¥₣₹])\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*(?:K|[BM](?:illions?)?)\b)?
```

On [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/EDxCjE/1)

In Python syntax:

```py
pattern = r"(?:\b[A-Z]{2,3}\s*[$€£¥₣₹]?|[$€£¥₣₹])\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*(?:K|[BM](?:illions?)?)\b)?"
```

Comment: I'm so sorry to disturb you again, sir, but this is exactly what I said in the comment above when some pattern works online but doesn't in a script. I've tried your pattern in action, and it shows me this (not catching the "M", "Million" and others, and also if a currency is specified with letters "JPY" i.e., shows as "None"):
https://imgur.com/a/9HrquLl

Comment: You must escape backslashes in string literals or use r-strings (preferred). It is really the common practice when defining regex string literals. See addition to answer.